# What are the good practices in layered programming?

Tags: theory, n-tier-architecture, layered

I have searched a lot on "What are the good practices in layered programming?"
but was not able to find a good link. I use java, and hibernate to connect to database.

Thanks

Comment: I've added the n-tier-architecture tag to your question. You could also search for multi-tier architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to following links

```
http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/good-programming-techniques/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260844(v=vs.60).aspx#cfr_bestprac
```

you should understand separation of concern in your application;how you can make each part of code reusable(at least to some extent);and inversion of control principle

`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control`

Comment: Thanks for the links but can you define clearly what logic is behind dividing code into smaller code chunks which definitely be reused and managed easily but i want to know about the generalized principle.

Comment: See it depends on what you are designing or working on.
In my advice you should study design patterns which are being used in industry to devise bigger applications and solve very big problems in a smooth and cheesy way. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern

Comment: Oh thanks that is what I was asking for.
Thanks a lot.